# Templates with const parameters does not dispatch as expected

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, constants

I'm trying to dispatch my calls in 2 different functions. One for *pointers* and the other for *references*. But as soon as I use the *const* qualifier, templates doesn't dispatch as expected. In my case, the `get_pixel` doesn't use any *const* qualifier because it is supposed to edit the given parameter. And `set_pixel` is supposed to use the given parameter but don't edit it and I would like those parameters to remain *const*.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Color>
inline int get_pixel(
    Color&  color)
{
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
inline int get_pixel(
    T components[])
{
    return 2;
}

template <typename Color>
inline int set_pixel(
    const Color&    color)
{
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
inline int set_pixel(
    const T components[])
{
    return 2;
}

template <typename Color>
inline int set_pixel_no_const(
    Color&  color)
{
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
inline int set_pixel_no_const(
    T components[])
{
    return 2;
}


int main()
{

    float c;
    float tab[1];

    std::cout << "Get PIXEL\n";
    std::cout << "Dispatch for c : " << get_pixel(c) << "\n"; // 1
    std::cout << "Dispatch for &c : " << get_pixel(&c) << "\n"; // 2
    std::cout << "Dispatch for tab : " << get_pixel(tab) << "\n"; // 2

    std::cout << "Set PIXEL\n";
    std::cout << "Dispatch for c : " << set_pixel(c) << "\n"; // 1
    std::cout << "Dispatch for &c : " << set_pixel(&c) << "\n"; // 1, Should be 2
    std::cout << "Dispatch for tab : " << set_pixel(tab) << "\n"; // 1, Should be 2

    std::cout << "Set PIXEL NO CONST\n";
    std::cout << "Dispatch for c : " << set_pixel_no_const(c) << "\n"; // 1
    std::cout << "Dispatch for &c : " << set_pixel_no_const(&c) << "\n"; // 2
    std::cout << "Dispatch for tab : " << set_pixel_no_const(tab) << "\n"; // 2

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea why the *const* qualifier is a problem here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template deduction doesn't work as a text substitution, but on the `T` as a whole.

When `T` in `const T` is deduced as `float*` you don't get `const float*`, but `float* const`.

Or `const (float*)`, if we had such a syntax.

Comment: Thanks Bo. Is there a way to have this working as expected ?

Comment: I have never used multiple templated getters and setters, so don't really see what you are trying to achive. Or how to do that. Except perhaps use different names.

Comment: I'm just trying to have a correct `const` parameter for both `pointer` and `reference` dispatch. The names are only for demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but i think basically this question boils down to this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int f(T const &)
{
    //std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    return 1;
}

template <typename T>
int f(T const *)
{
    //std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    float c = 1.f;
    float * addr = &c;
    float const * addr_const = &c;
    f(c); // 1
    f(&c); // 1 you expected 2
    f(addr); // 1 you expected 2
    f(addr_const); // 2 as you expect
    return 0;
}
```

Your const array function parameter is the same as a const pointer parameter in the function declaration(so i put it in this way in the example).

I think the first function is the base template, while the second version is a more specialized version (since it only takes pointers to const T). So the const reference one gets chosen when you pass a pointer to non const. Except in the case you really pass it a pointer to const as argument.

If you use gcc (i think) you can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to display the deduced arguments

Comment: Thanks for the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` tip phön, it works great !